# Casting to custom type a PostgreSQL array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a Rails (5.2) app I have the `Project` model with a `tags` attribute defined as a Postgresql array.

```
  create_table :projects do |t|
    ...
    t.text :tags, array: true, default: []
    ...
  end
```

Instead of handling tags as strings I'd like to cast them to `Tag`s objects

```
class Tag
  ...
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  ...
end
```

To achieve so I'm trying to use the attributes API that comes with Rails 5.

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :tags, TagType.new, array: true
  ...
end

class TagType < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
  def cast(names)
    names.split(',').map { |name| Tag.new(name) }
  end
end
```

This kind of work, it creates `Tag`s object but the first and last have brackets in the name.

```
Project.create(tags: ['one', 'two', 'three'])
Project.first.tags.map(&:name) #=> ['{one', 'two', 'three}']
```

Is there a better way than manually removing the brackets from `names` in `TagType` to get proper `Tag`s?

Trying to find in Rails code where the array value is parsed but no luck so far.

Comment: Try starting with [`connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/array.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.1/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/array.rb) in the ActiveRecord source, decoding arrays is a little more complicated than a simple `String#split` call as you have to deal with things like `'{"a b", c, d}'` and the like.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I ended up to use.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question, could be useful information for future seekers.

Answer (score 4):

This is a more generic version of this, which is what I was looking for:

```rb
# config/initializers/text_array.rb
class TextArrayType < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
  include ActiveModel::Type::Helpers::Mutable

  def cast(value)
    case
    when value.is_a?(Array)
      value
    when value.present?
      value.split(/[\s,]+/)
    else
      []
    end
  end

  def deserialize(value)
    PG::TextDecoder::Array.new.decode(value)
  end

  def serialize(value)
    PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode(value)
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Type.register(:text_array, TextArrayType)
```

This will enable you to add tags like:

```rb
create_table :projects do |t|
  ...
  t.text :tags, array: true, default: []
  ...
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :tags, :text_array
end
```

What I wanted to achieve was to be able to add tags both as an array and as a comma separated list like:

```rb
Project.new(tags: ["x", "y", "z"] # => tags: ["x", "y", "z"]
Project.new(tags: "x, y, z") # => tags: ["x", "y", "z"]
```

This will enable you to add multiple tags in a form as a comma separated list:

```rb
f.text_area :tags, value: @project.tags.join(", ")
```

as well as managing tags as an array everywhere else in the project.

Answer (score 3):

Here the code I ended up with

```
class TagType < ActiveRecord::Type::Value
  include ActiveModel::Type::Helpers::Mutable

  def cast(name)
    Tag.new(name)
  end

  def deserialize(names)
    PG::TextDecoder::Array.new.decode(names).map { |name| cast(name) }
  end

  def serialize(tags)
    PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode(tags.map(&:name))
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.